# A norm discontinuous C0-semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathcal L(X)$ be a strongly continuous semigroup.

The notes I'm reading state that the map $T$ is not necessarily continuous when $\mathcal L(X)$ has the topology induced by the operator norm, while for every fixed $x\in X$ the map $[0,\infty)\to X$ given by $t\mapsto T(t)x$ is continuous. While I see the latter statement it's not clear to me why the former doesn't hold, is there a simple example of a C0-semigroup of operators on some Banach space which is not continuous in norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semigroup on a Banach space is norm continuous if and only if its generator is bounded. So every $C_0$-semigroup generated by an unbounded operator gives you an example.

To be more concrete, you can take the heat semigroup
$$
P_t\colon L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^d),\,P_tf(x)=(4\pi t)^{-d/2}\int e^{-\frac{|x-y|}{4t}}f(y)\,dy
$$
for any $p\in [1,\infty)$.

Its generator is $\Delta$ on a suitable domain, which is certainly not bounded. Other examples include the translation semigroup $T_t f(x)=f(x+t)$ on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup $T_t f(x)=\int f(e^{-t} x+\sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}y)\,dy$ on $C_b(X)$ and many more.

Comment: Do you know of a book in which I can read the proof of that equivalence by any chance?

Comment: Virtually any book on operator semigroups (at least I hope so). I like the book by Engel and Nagel.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out